# How to add date stamps to record journal entries

Tags: date, latex

Basically I want the document to serve as some kind of journal, to record what I've done every day, so I need to add a date stamp in every entry. It should be like this:

> 9/14/2015
>
> added a comma to the poem.
>
> 9/15/2015
>
> comma deleted.

I know `\date{\today}` will add the date of the last compilation, but that's not what I want, and the google results are mostly about this (might be I'm search for the wrong key word).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `isodate` package provides commands to switch between different date formats. You can use the following command to print a date, see the [manual](http://mirror.unicorncloud.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/isodate/isodate.pdf) for details.

```
\printdate{09/14/2015}
```

The list in your example looks like a revision history, if so, take a look at the `vhistory` package.

Here is an example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,num,USenglish]{isodate}
\dateinputformat{american} % mm/dd/yyyy

\usepackage{vhistory}

\begin{document}
\begin{versionhistory}
  \vhEntry{1.0}{\printdate{09/14/2015}}{Olivier Ma}{added a comma to the poem.}
  \vhEntry{1.1}{\printdate{09/15/2015}}{Olivier Ma}{comma deleted.}
\end{versionhistory}
\end{document}
```

[image]